# Java AnnotationProcessor can not generate code with gradle 5.1.1

Tags: java, gradle

I write an annotation processor following [this blog](https://medium.com/@iammert/annotation-processing-dont-repeat-yourself-generate-your-code-8425e60c6657), the code has no problem, but it just can not generate the file, then I found out is the Gradle version.

**my Gradle setting :**

`root -> build.gradle:`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
}
```

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

So, when I downgrade the Gradle version to 4.6, everything is fine.

**my changed Gradle setting:**

`root -> build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

I looked up the doc about Gradle 5.x, got nothing. Is there some changed behavior can cause this problem?

What should I do when I want to use Gradle 5.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem on upgrade of Android Studio (3.3 -> 3.4) (This upgrades gradle from 4.10.1 -> 5.1.1). Not 4.6 exactly but I noticed no breaking change from 4.6 -> 4.10 so I assume the following will work.
I'm using kapt, and an annotation processor I built as a java module. Everything worked fine before the update.

My solution was:
 - Upgrade `com.google.auto.service:auto-service` to `1.0-rc6`
 - Add `annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6"` to the annotation processor's build.gradle file.

Found my answer via these:
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7941
- https://github.com/ishaigor/annotation-processor-sample/commit/d7645914b9f53a5f350c7098973f3554c48e75d8

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks.     ```implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc5' ``` add this line to processor's gradle file : 
   ```annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc5' ```  it works!!!